# How can I prevent Cassandra nodes from making changes to triggers

Tags: cassandra

Triggers in Cassandra is implemented as java classes. How can I prevent a node from switching out a trigger class with e.g. malicious code? I do not want the node owners to have access to the database or triggers at all.

When creating the trigger, I use this syntax:

`CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.InvertedIndex';`

From my understanding, another node could create a java class with the same name and place it in the trigger folder, and that would be executed instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since [triggers are created on a table level](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html), one could do something like this to prevent a role to be able to create them,

```
REVOKE CREATE
 ON keyspace_name.table_name
 FROM role_name;
```

or do it [at the keyspace level](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlRevoke.html) itself.

If you're granting access to someone directly on the C* cluster nodes itself, maybe try restricting to only read-level access alone for that user to C* cluster config files, data directories, etc., as an another option.

Comment: Thank you, but the trigger already exist. How can I prevent the other nodes from replacing the trigger class file with another? Since they own the node, they will have full access to the file system and config files.

Comment: This is a classic seggregation of duties problem.